# pdftk populated texraea is not scrollable

Tags: multiline, php-pdftk

I am using php pdftk to take data out of a mysql database and put it in a bunch of different fields on a PDF. My issue is a few of the fields potentially have long text however instead of then showing an up/down scroll bar or even being able to scroll up or down to read all the text it seems to just get cutoff.
I am wondering if there is a specific pdftk tag or something I should use to ensure if the field has multiple rows that I can see a scroll bar to scroll up and down to ready all that would be entered in.

Here is how the pdf looks. when I load it via an iframe in the browser notice the textarea labeled HPI as multiple rows of text but no scroll bar or indication you can scroll up or down.
[image]
However if I open the template pdf file in adobe and type a bunch into that field see screenshot below you can then see a up/down scroll bar in the field labeled HPI
[image]

Here is the code

```
   namespace Classes;
   use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

   class GeneratePDF {


       public function generate($data, $patientid)
       {      

              try {

                    $filename = "$patientid.pdf";

                    $pdf = new Pdf('./imports/the_template.pdf');
                    $pdf->fillForm($data)
                    ->saveAs( './imports/generated_consults/' . $filename);
                    //->send( $filename . '.pdf');

                    return $filename;

              }
              catch(Exception $e)
              {
                    return $e->getMessage();
              }
  

         }
     }
```

Comment: Would you be able to upload some code? (Just the bare minimum to recreate the issue)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your *textarea* is a text field of an interactive form. The content of interactive forms can be updated using the [*fill_form*](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-fill-form) operation of *pdftk*.

Interactive forms are described in the [PDF Reference, version 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) at section *8.6 – Interactive Forms*. Available options and flags for text fields are described in tables 8.69, 8.70, 8.71, and 8.77.

As I understand the reference, you have to set the *Multiline* flag (bit position 13) and clear the *DoNotScroll* flag (bit position 24). Beside that, there does not seem to be another option for that. However, I would also try if using a RichText (bit position 26) makes a difference.

---

If you don't modify the values of fields in a form but directly inject text objects into the PDF (I'm not sure if *pdftk* can even do this), then there might be no easy solution. From the PDF Reference, version 1.7, chapter 2:

> A page’s appearance is described by a PDF *content stream*, which contains a sequence of *graphics objects* to be painted on the page. This appearance is fully specified; all layout and formatting decisions have already been made by the application generating the content stream.

This means there is no automatic *line breaking* (aka. *word wrapping*) in PDFs. I could also not find the ability to include scroll bars within the document. After all, a goal of PDF is to achive a consistent appearance on all devices.